# height 100% con Jquery pero con transición

Tags: jquery, css

Hola como puedo hacer que el alto cambie al darle a mostrar más, pero de forma lenta, no de golpe.

```js
var mostrar = true;

$( "#mostrar" ).click(function() {
  if(mostrar==true){
    $(".rowSucate").css("height", "100%");
    $(".rowSucate").css("transition","1s");
    mostrar=false;
  }
  else
  {
    $(".rowSucate").css("height", "46px");
    $(".rowSucate").css("transition","1s");
    mostrar=true;
  }
});
```

```css
.rowSucate {
    height: 46px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#mostrar {
color: red;
}
.categorias {
    background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="col-8">
<body style="background:#333">
<h3 style="color:#fff;">Subcategoria <span class="pull-right" id="mostrar">Mostrar más</span></h3>
        <div class="dropdown-divider margb4"></div>
        <div class="categorias">
          <div class="rowSucate">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="form-check col-6">
                <input class="form-check-input pruebas" type="checkbox" name="subcategoria[]" id="subcategorias{{ $sub->id }}" value="{{ $sub->id }}">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="subcategorias{{ $sub->id }}">Opcion 1</label>
              </div> 
          </div>
          <div class="row">
              <div class="form-check col-6">
                <input class="form-check-input pruebas" type="checkbox" name="subcategoria[]" id="subcategorias{{ $sub->id }}" value="{{ $sub->id }}">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="subcategorias{{ $sub->id }}">Opcion 1</label>
              </div> 
          </div>
          <div class="row">
              <div class="form-check col-6">
                <input class="form-check-input pruebas" type="checkbox" name="subcategoria[]" id="subcategorias{{ $sub->id }}" value="{{ $sub->id }}">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="subcategorias{{ $sub->id }}">Opcion 1</label>
              </div> 
          </div>
          <div class="row">
              <div class="form-check col-6">
                <input class="form-check-input pruebas" type="checkbox" name="subcategoria[]" id="subcategorias{{ $sub->id }}" value="{{ $sub->id }}">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="subcategorias{{ $sub->id }}">Opcion 1</label>
              </div> 
          </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar la función [animate()](https://api.jquery.com/animate/) de JQuery, estableciendo la duración de la animación. Además, no utilices porcentajes para indicar el height, ya que eso puede dar lugar a [problemas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11504755/animating-a-div-to-100-height). Por eso lo cambié a 100px.

```js
var mostrar = true;

$( "#mostrar" ).click(function() {
  if(mostrar==true){
    $(".rowSucate").animate({height: "100px"},'slow');
    mostrar=false;
  }
  else
  {
    $(".rowSucate").animate({height: "46px"}, 'slow');
    mostrar=true;
  }
});
```

```css
.rowSucate {
    height: 46px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#mostrar {
color: red;
}
.categorias {
    background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="col-8">
<body style="background:#333">
<h3 style="color:#fff;">Subcategoria <span class="pull-right" id="mostrar">Mostrar más</span></h3>
        <div class="dropdown-divider margb4"></div>
        <div class="categorias">
          <div class="rowSucate">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="form-check col-6">
                <input class="form-check-input pruebas" type="checkbox" name="subcategoria[]" id="subcategorias{{ $sub->id }}" value="{{ $sub->id }}">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="subcategorias{{ $sub->id }}">Opcion 1</label>
              </div> 
          </div>
          <div class="row">
              <div class="form-check col-6">
                <input class="form-check-input pruebas" type="checkbox" name="subcategoria[]" id="subcategorias{{ $sub->id }}" value="{{ $sub->id }}">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="subcategorias{{ $sub->id }}">Opcion 1</label>
              </div> 
          </div>
          <div class="row">
              <div class="form-check col-6">
                <input class="form-check-input pruebas" type="checkbox" name="subcategoria[]" id="subcategorias{{ $sub->id }}" value="{{ $sub->id }}">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="subcategorias{{ $sub->id }}">Opcion 1</label>
              </div> 
          </div>
          <div class="row">
              <div class="form-check col-6">
                <input class="form-check-input pruebas" type="checkbox" name="subcategoria[]" id="subcategorias{{ $sub->id }}" value="{{ $sub->id }}">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="subcategorias{{ $sub->id }}">Opcion 1</label>
              </div> 
          </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hola y gracias por tu respuesta, pero esque necesito que saque el 100% del div, ya que es dinamico y puede crecer según tenga más registros

Comment: Mira la respuesta @kalia

Comment: Entiendo... Podrías intentar esta solución: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15393766/javascript-jquery-animate-to-dynamic-height

Comment: Hola @kalia funciono perfecto lo del foro, si modificas la respuesta por la que he puesto la marco como buena, gracias por tu atención